# Accessing C++ arrays passed via COM in C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling, idl

I have a legacy COM class that passes C++ array pointers without using SAFEARRAY.  (It was probably implemented before that existed.)   I'd like to implement an interface in C# without change the COM interface.  In the IDL, the function is defined as:

```
    HRESULT SetProperties([in] int cProperties,
                  [in, size_is(cProperties)] BSTR Properties[],
                  [in, size_is(cProperties)] VARIANT Values[]);
```

When I reference the DLL in a C# project and select implement interface, it turns into the following:

```
   unsafe public void SetProperties(int cProperties, ref string Properties, ref object Values)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Is there some way to access the Properties and Values as arrays in C#?

I have taken this issue up again.  It appears that the partial answer is in Marshalling.   I can redo the C# function as the following:

```
public void SetProperties(int cProperties,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.BStr, SizeParamIndex=0)] ref string[] Properties,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex=0)] ref object[] Values)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Now the C# compiler says that the COM interface function SetProperties() has not been implemented.   It's still looking for a function with first type signature, according to the Visual Studio object browser.

Is there any way to implement the interface using Marshalled arguments?

Comment: have you looked at http://www.pinvoke.net/ for examples?

Comment: Have you tried `SetProperties(int cProperties, string[] Properties, object[] Values)`  (unsafe is not necessary) ? PS: BSTR, VARIANT and SAFEARRAY were born the same day (or so).

Comment: When I use string[], I get an error that SetProperties is not implemented for the interface.    Looking a pinvoke,net doesn't help because I can declare the function however I need; in this case **tlbimp** is providing the external function definition.

Comment: I guess the original developers made an explicit decision not to use SAFEARRAY.  I can't ask them why because they are no longer around.